# How do I use a .resx file in a class library inside a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, class-library

So I have got a library that hosts all my images. This works fine for my WinForms controls; however, I am having difficult using this same class library's resources in WPF.

```
MyApp.Resources //Is my control library project.
Resources //Is the folder that contains all my images at the root of the project.
```

How do I reference an image inside a WPF control from my class library?

**What I have tried:**

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyApp.Resources;Resources/manage.png" />
```

**--UserControl Property**

```
Resources="pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Resources;Resources.resx">
```

Comment: Check out this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new RESX file.
2. In this file add ur files.
3. Check ur RESX file in Solution Explorer in VS and change the build action from Embedded Resource into Resource.
4. Open RESX file and change the access modifier from Internal into Public.
5. Create a new Resource Dictionary file (eg. Files.xaml):

> ```
> <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">  
>    <BitmapImage x:Key="someImage" 
>                 UriSource="/YourAppNamespace;component/Resources/image.png" />
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ```

6. Import the dictionary in your window or app resources:

> ```
> <ResourceDictionary>
>    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>       <ResourceDictionary Source="Files.xaml" />
>    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ```

7. Use ur image in WPF app:

> ```
> <Image Source="{StaticResource someImage}" />
> ```